# Issues with beans in the migration (some nodes don't migrate, some migrate old revisions)

Tags: migrations, 9

I am trying to do a migration from Drupal 7 to Drupal 9. Most seems to migrate okay but I noticed the following problems:

- I am missing some nodes
- Some nodes migrated only old revisions of the node (IE: In the live site a node has 8 revisions, and the migration only migrated the first 2, leaving the most recent of the 2 as the live content, which is a review from 2015. The most recent review in the site is from 2021)

The issue probably comes from one of those notices, I am just not too sure how to fix it or debug them:

```
The "bean" entity type does not exist. (/app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php:143)
[notice] Cannot change the field type for an existing field storage. The field storage node.field_thumbnail has the type entity_reference. (/app/web/core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldStorageConfig.php:375)
[notice] Cannot change the field type for an existing field storage. The field storage node.field_event_date has the type daterange. (/app/web/core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldStorageConfig.php:375)
[notice] The "bean" entity type does not exist. (/app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php:143)
 [notice] Attempt to create a field field_bean_text that does not exist on entity type bean. (/app/web/core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldConfig.php:315)
 [notice] Attempt to create a field field_link_to that does not exist on entity type bean. (/app/web/core/modules/field/src/Entity/FieldConfig.php:315)
 [notice] The configuration property settings.required_summary.0 doesn't exist. (/app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Schema/ArrayElement.php:76)
 [notice] The configuration property settings.required_summary.0 doesn't exist. (/app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Schema/ArrayElement.php:76)
```

Any tips to migrate beans? I tried using the module "bean migrate" but then those notices turn in to:

```
 [notice] Upgrading bean:homepage_information_block_base
 [error]  Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'uuid' cannot be null: INSERT INTO "block_content" ("revision_id", "type", "uuid", "langcode") VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3); Array
(
    [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => homepage_information_block_base
    [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => und
)
 in Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\ExceptionHandler->handleExecutionException() (line 50 of /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Driver/mysql/ExceptionHandler.php). 
 [notice] SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'uuid' cannot be null: INSERT INTO "block_content" ("revision_id", "type", "uuid", "langcode") VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3); Array
(
    [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => homepage_information_block_base
    [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => und
)
```

I am fairly familiar with Drupal, just not so much with Migrations, so any general tips to help me debug/fix would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I eventually figured this out. I am not sure why I was not getting the error, but somewhere in the migration process I eventually found out my docker container did not have enough memory assigned for the process. The migration seemed to finish, but parts of it crashed/timed out and didnt migrate.

All I did was increase the memory and timeout time and it worked. The other errors were probably result of that and/or irrelevant.